# VLCJ, JVM crash when VideoAdjustments are enabled

Tags: java, vlcj

I am experimenting with **vlcj** library and I am facing an issue with video adjustments. In details, the **JVM crashes** when the video ends or is stopped without disabling video adjustments first.

As stated in the documentation, I am enabling video adjustments after the video started playing. After that I am able to change saturation, hue and other parameters without problems.

I have tried disabling video adjustments as soon as I receive the STOPPED or FINISHED events, but this does not solve the problem.

I am using VLCj 4.1.0 and the code to enable video adjustment is just the following line.

```
this.mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().video().setAdjustVideo(true);
```

**[UPDATE 1]**:

The following code reproduces the issue. When the video ends, the crash happens.
Note that if the last line is commented out, the crash does not happen.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;

public class SelfContainedMediaPlayer {

    private final JFrame frame;
    private static SelfContainedMediaPlayer selfContainedMediaPlayer;
    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        selfContainedMediaPlayer = new SelfContainedMediaPlayer();
    }

    public SelfContainedMediaPlayer(){
        frame = new JFrame("My First Media Player");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1920, 1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().play("path to video");
        mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().video().setAdjustVideo(true);
    }
}
```

Just a few more details about my environment.

- I am using Windows 10
- vlcj version 4.1.0
- Installed VLC version is 3.0.6 64bit
- java version "11.0.1"

Any suggestion?
Thanks

**[UPDATE 2]:**

I found the problem.
As I anticipated in one of the comments below, I was testing the **vlcj-player** application I found [here](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player), and I noticed that the problem was not present with that application.
After some digging, I found out that the `JFrame` containing the video needs a `TransferHandler`. 
So, I solved the problem just by passing a `TransferHandler` instance to the frame like below.

```
frame.setTransferHandler(new CustomTransferHandler());
```

`CustomTransferHandler` is a class that extends `TransferHandler`.

Unfortunately, I still don't understand why this is causing a crash of the JVM.

Comment: Maybe post a complete self contained class that demonstrates the problem, it may be something other than the video adjustments I suspect.

Comment: I have update my question with some code that can repro the issue. I cannot say it is directly caused by the video adjustment feature, but I am sure that that triggers it. I have started having this problem the moment I have started testing that feature.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: VLC 3.0.7 was just released, might be worth trying that.

Comment: I've just tried updating to VLC 3.0.7 but the problem persists. I have also tried checking out the vlcj-player sample project https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player. This works perfectly. I can play video, enable video adjustments, change saturation/hue/etc... with not problems. I don't understand why I have this JVM crash with the other code.

Comment: Your update 2 makes no sense. Honestly, this all smacks of your media player being garbage collected. I always recommend you put a Thread.currentThread().join() before your application exit, and make sure you keep a reference to your vlcj objects, just to rule out this type of problem.

Comment: I agree with you that it does not make sense. That's why I wrote that I still don't understand the root cause of the crash. I was just reporting that setting the TransferHandler, for some reason, solved the issue.
By the way, I also tried Thread.currentThread().join(), which makes perfectly sense, but unfortunately that does not prevent the JVM to crash. 
I tried the same code on two different machines, and I am observing the exact same behavior.